# replaceAll with '*'

Tags: java, string, replaceall

`replaceAll` with a value that contains '*' is throwing an exception.

I tried this

```
String tmp = "M ******* k";

tmp = tmp.replaceAll("****","NOT");

System.out.println("TMP is :"+tmp);
```

and I am getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
```

Why does `replaceAll` with `*` have this behavior and how do I overcome with this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first argument in [**replaceAll()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression. The character '*' has a special meaning in regular expressions.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

So you have to escape it, if you want to match the literal `character '*'.`

Use `"\\*".`

[oracle forum on the same](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2064440?tstart=40830)

Answer (score 4):

You can check this code for reference:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
          String tmp = "M ******* k";

          tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\*","NOT");

          System.out.println("TMP is :"+tmp);
    }
```

'*' is regular expression special char in java.So you need to follow rules of regular expressions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\*+","NOT");
```

[More](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiy3oIBDA/index.html);

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `*`s:

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\*\\*\\*\\*","NOT");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = tmp.replace("****","NOT"); // No regular expression
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\*\\*\\*\\*","NOT");
```

The second alternative is the regular expression one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the asterisks? As the `PatternSyntaxException` points out, `*` is a special character which requires a character class before it.

More appropriate way to do it would be:

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\*\\*\\*\\*", "NOT");
```